# how to escape special character and set constrain in end of regex like . or space not allowed at the end of string

Tags: java, regex

All except

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
\0 (NULL)
cannot end in space or dot
```

so far i have done:

```
return Pattern.compile( "[<\\>\\/\\:\\|\\?\\*\"'\\\\]" ).matcher( name ).find();
```

but *cannot end in space or dot* condition does not meet .

Comment: https://regexr.com/ is a good place to start in debugging regexes.

Comment: You don't need to escape *everything* in a character class. Also, it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Do you have sample strings and their expected outputs?

Comment: if someone write project name that include special character and have space in the end and . (dot) in the end theen it returen false ..

Comment: and special character that are not allowed are mention above

Comment: Please clarify: you don't want the string to have any special character, and it should also not end with a space or full stop, right?

Comment: i dont want any above mention character anywhere in string  and  space and . (dot) in the end of the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
boolean check1 = Pattern.compile(".*[<|>|:|\"|/|\\\\|\\|\\?|\\*|[\\\\0]].*").matcher(name).find();
boolean check2 = Pattern.compile(".*[\\s|\\.]$").matcher(name).find();
return (check1 || check2);
```

It returns `true` if anything is wrong in the name.

Comment: pak>istan     it should return true : but its returning false :

Comment: @NomanArshad If your question has been answered, please make sure to **accept the answer** for further references :)